# Results for escaped search with haystack/solr not correct

Tags: django, solr, django-haystack

I am using the standard lucene query parser, and I have the following query:

```
q=\*
```

I expect this (since the * is quoted) to return documents that actually have * somewhere. Instead, what I am getting is everything back.

The same thing happens with other queries like: `q=\*\:\*`

What can I do within the standard query parser (without moving to dismax) to do escaped searches?

Thank you

Comment: What is the type of your field?

Comment: It is a text field. Since searches go through an additional, the end q looks like `q=(\*\:\*) AND (other_field:value)`. The interesting thing is if I did `q=(\*\:\*)` by itself, it tries to match documents with it (returning nothing), but when I add the AND clause everything comes back. It is as if AND is expanding the search rather than limiting it.